Resolve certificate issues with Ceph
I've just deployed a three-node Ceph cluster using cephadm. I'm seeing SSL-related errors due to the fact we have an SSL-inspecting firewall/proxy.
The CA is added to all the hosts so they're able to fetch the docker images successfully but any time the containers try to access the internet, they get SSL errors.
Is there any way to either configure Ceph globally not to verify SSL certificates or to add the CA? Manually injecting the CA into each and every docker container isn't a feasible solution.

It's not a complete answer, but the comments are quite limited. The first question would be, do the Ceph containers really need internet access? If it's only required for pulling images, I would recommend to deploy your own container registry. This would also allow a better control over container versions.
To deploy certificates into containers automatically, you can utilize the extra_container_args. Here's an example of my RGW specification:
service_type: rgw
service_id: myid
service_name: rgw.myid
placement:
  count: 2
extra_container_args:
- -v=/var/lib/ca-certificates/:/var/lib/ca-certificates/:ro
- -v=/var/lib/ca-certificates/ca-bundle.pem:/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt:ro
spec:
  rgw_frontend_port: 443
  rgw_realm: default
  rgw_zone: default
  ssl: true

This maps the entire directory /var/lib/ca-certificates/ into the RGW containers. Additionally, the ca-bundle.pem is mapped to ca-bundle.crt. In my case, the host machines are running a different OS (openSUSE) than the containers (CentOS).
This should be applicable to any kind of certificate you need inside of the containers.
After changing the service specs (you'll probably need that in all daemons, it seems), you can redeploy the services. But be careful and test your changes first, redeploy only a single daemon and check before moving on:
ceph orch daemon redeploy rgw.{some_daemon}

If you have the impression that your changes worked, you can also redeploy an entire service:
ceph orch redeploy rgw.myid

